# How to count how many entries per column in a dataset with >1000 columns?

Tags: r

I would like to find out how many entries each column has? I have over 1000 columns of data, whilst some contain NA.

For example:

```
Date  A   B
1990  NA  NA
1991  1   NA
1992  2   2
1993  3   3
1994  4   NA
1995  5   3
1996  NA  NA
1997  7   8
1998  8   2
1999  NA  NA
2000  8   4
```

Below is the result I would like.

```
A   B  
8   6
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Thank you! How would I exclude the date column from this?

Comment: `colSums(!is.na(df[-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
colSums(Negate(is.na)(df))
```

or

```
lengths(Map(na.omit,df))
```

which gives

```
Date    A    B 
  11    8    6
```